# Spark job fails on image pull in Iguazio

Tags: mlops, nuclio, spark-operator, mlrun

I am using code examples in the MLRun documentation for running a spark job on Iguazio platform. Docs say I can use a default spark docker image provided by the platform, but when I try to run the job the pod hangs with Error ImagePullBackOff. Here is the function spec item I am using:

```
my_func.spec.use_default_image = True
```

How do I configure Iguazio to use the default spark image that is supposed to be included in the platform?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the default image to the cluster docker registry. There is one image for remote spark and one image for spark operator. Those images contain all the necessary dependencies for remote Spark and Spark Operator.

See the code below.

```
# This section has to be invoked once per MLRun/Iguazio upgrade
from mlrun.runtimes import RemoteSparkRuntime
RemoteSparkRuntime.deploy_default_image()
from mlrun.runtimes import Spark3Runtime
Spark3Runtime.deploy_default_image()
```

Once these images are deployed (to the cluster docker registry), your function with function spec `“use_default_image” = True` will be able to pull the image and deploy.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for pointing that out!